# How to parse dynamic JSON with Retrofit 2 (+Nested objects)

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to parse JSON response that looks like this.

```
{
    "Cryptsy": {
        "AMC": [
            "BTC"
        ],
        "CIRC": [
            "BTC"
        ],
        "SYNC": [
            "BTC"
        ]
    },
    "Bitstamp": {
        "EUR": [
            "USD"
        ],
        "ETH": [
            "USD",
            "EUR"
        ],
        "XRP": [
            "USD",
            "EUR",
            "BTC"
        ]
    },
    // ...
    // More objects...
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, this one has the dynamic keys and each values are also objects with dynamic keys. I tried parse this using retrofit2 and GsonConverter but it causes the exception

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I think it's because the JSON is nested and all objects don't have any fixed keys.

Here's my code.

***PairListResponse.java***

```
// This is the GSON model class

class PairListResponse {

    private Map<String, Map<String, String[]>> exchangePairs;

    PairListResponse() {
    }

    Map<String, Map<String, String[]>> getExchangePairs() {
        return exchangePairs;
    }

    void setExchangePairs(Map<String, Map<String, String[]>> exchangePairs) {
        this.exchangePairs = exchangePairs;
    }

    Map<String, String[]> getTradingPairs(String fromSymbol) {
        return exchangePairs.get(fromSymbol);
    }
}
```

PairListDeserializer.java

```
public class PairListDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<PairListResponse> {

    private static final String TAG = PairListDeserializer.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public PairListResponse deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        final Map<String, Map<String, String[]>> exchangePairs = readPairMap(jsonObject);
        PairListResponse result = new PairListResponse();
        result.setExchangePairs(exchangePairs);
        return result;
    }

    @Nullable
    private Map<String, Map<String, String[]>> readPairMap(@NonNull final JsonObject jsonObject) {
        // Initializing Hashmap for the outer object
        final Map<String, Map<String, String[]>> result = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
            String exchange = entry.getKey();
            String fromSymbol;
            String[] toSymbols;
            JsonObject fsymbolObj = entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject();

        // Initializing Hashmap for inner objects
            final Map<String, String[]> pairsPerCoin = new HashMap<>();

            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> inner_entry : fsymbolObj.entrySet()) {
                fromSymbol = inner_entry.getKey();
                toSymbols = toStringArray(inner_entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray());
                pairsPerCoin.put(fromSymbol, toSymbols);
            }
            result.put(exchange, pairsPerCoin);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String[] toStringArray(JsonArray array) {
        if (array == null) return null;
        String[] arr = new String[array.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = array.get(i).toString();
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I made a dumbest mistake! 
In my retrofit API call, I forgot to set the correct model class name.

```
public interface TradingPairAPICall {
    @GET("exchanges")
    Call<String> getAllPairList();
}
```

In fact, it needs to be

```
Call<PairListResponse> getAllPairList();
```

I changed it and it successfully worked.